# .htaccess mod rewrite subdomain to folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have searched and read a lot... but nothing works.

I'm trying to rewrite

*subdomain.domain.com* to *domain.com/folder/* and then, when this is working, I guess it will be easy to have *domain.com/folder/subdomain*.

I have tried placing this in an .htaccess file, which is in the root of the server.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/ [L]
```

But I get a Not Found error:

> The requested URL /folder/ was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at subdomain.domain.com Port 80

But http://domain.com/folder/ does exist.

And redirection does work but that's not what I want:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/folder/subdomain/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

In order to help me understand what was going on, I changed [L] to [R] (in the first piece of code),

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/ [R]
```

and the redirect, which is an infinite loop, goes to

http://subdomain.domain.com/folder/
not to
http://domain.com/folder/
as intended...

How can I correct this? How can I make the rewrite "leave" the subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule . http://domain.com/folder/%1%{REQUEST_URI}
```

that means subdomain.domain.com/somefile.html -> domain.com/folder/subdomain/somefile.html.
Subdomain must point to the same virtual host as domain.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but this code redirects, just like the one I provided above, and said that it wasn't what I wanted. It doesn't rewrite.
So, no luck here...

Comment: @nunomira if you want an external redirect to /folder/ where you going to store the value of 'subdomain' as it lost? Odd internal redirects do not make sense.